# Don't show row if X X Y exists but show if it does not

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to get rid of a row combination if a different row combination exists.

I want to prioritise rows where `Lidl` is in `Germany`, and don't want rows where `Lidl` is in `Austria`. However, I might also have a row with `Aldi` that only has `Austria`.

Hence, I cant just filter out `Austria` by doing`WHERE Country <> 'Austria'`

Example data:

[image: Example Data]

Any tips?

Thanks

Comment: Are there more than one combination that you do not want?

Comment: Yes, there could be an infinite amount of stores selling an infinite amount of fruits. However, if a store sells the same fruit and colour combination in Austria and Germany, I only want to have the record of Germany and not Austria. If Germany does not exist, then I want to see the Austria record.

Comment: Please add more examples of the input table and also show us the output you would want to receive for that table. Please pu t it in text, not an image.

Comment: The traditional solution is to assign a "score" to the rows inside each subgroup. The score  is computed with any ad-hoc logic (as the one you mentioned). Then it's as simple as keeping the row with the highest score per subgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
create table test as (
  select 1 as id, 'Apple' as fruit, 'Lidl' as store, 
    'Green' as colour, 'Germany' as country
  union all
  select 2 as id, 'Apple' as fruit, 'Lidl' as store, 
    'Green' as colour, 'Austria' as country
  union all
  select 3 as id, 'Orange' as fruit, 'Aldi' as store, 
    'Yellow' as colour, 'Austria' as country
);

with has_germany as (
select fruit, store, colour, country,
    first_value(country) over (partition by store 
        order by case when country = 'Germany' then 0 else 1 end
        ) as has_germany
from test
)
select fruit, store, colour, country
from has_germany
where (has_germany = 'Germany' and country = 'Germany' )
   or has_germany <> 'Germany';
```

The first statement just sets up your input table (next time please put you source data in a plain text format).  The query just detects if 'Germany' is in the store's list of countries and then applies the WHERE logic of 'if it has Germany then it much be country Germany'.

I'm not 100% sure this covers all the corner cases you need but should get you started.